# Different division results dependent on IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, integer-division

I use Python 2.7 within Python(x,y), a scientific-oriented Python distribution based on Qt and Spyder as IDE.
When I use standard floor division of integers in the standard Python IDE the result is that of a floor division:

```
>>> 7/2
3
```

However,  when I use the Spyder IDE the result is that of a true division

```
>>> 7/2
3.5
```

I knwo that true division became standard in Python 3.0 using "/" but in my case both IDEs use the same Python distribution 2.7.
Why is this happening?
Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: You can also get that behavior in 2.7 by `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) Please update to version `2.3.1` to see the same behavior in both a regular Python console and the Spyder one.

Given the confusion you are reporting, we decided to not run `from __future__ import division` and other things while starting our Python consoles.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the most authoritative an answer can get.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder's default startup script does `from __future__ import division`.